# can soundex be used on portion of a column in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to use soundex to compare portion of a column with search term? For example if a user searches "fiftythree" - it will find "Nirve Sports Fifty-Three Cruiser in Gold Metallic". I tried combining soundex with locate function but got an error.  Here is my php code:

```
$soundex = soundex($keyword);
$soundexPrefix = substr($soundex, 0, 2); 
$sql = "SELECT name ".
"FROM products WHERE SOUNDEX(LOCATE('$keyword', name)) LIKE '%$soundexPrefix%'";
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to break up each word and do the `SOUNDEX` comparison, which is exactly what this function I'm going to tell you about does.

### Using the function

Example usage: `SELECT p.name FROM products p WHERE soundex_match('fiftythree', p.name, ' ')`

It takes 3 arguments:

- needle: The word you are looking for
- haysack: The string of words among which you are searching
- splitChar: The whitespace charater that’ll split the string into
  single words. Generally it is the space(‘ ‘)

If any word in haystack sounds similar to needle, the function will return 1 and 0 otherwise.

### **Creating the function in your database**

So go into your database (phpMyAdmin or the command line) and execute this, you only need to do it this one time):

```
drop function if exists soundex_match;
delimiter $$
create function soundex_match (needle varchar(128), haystack text, splitChar varchar(1)) returns tinyint
  deterministic
  begin
    declare spacePos int;
    declare searchLen int default length(haystack);
    declare curWord varchar(128) default '';
    declare tempStr text default haystack;
    declare tmp text default '';
    declare soundx1 varchar(64) default soundex(needle);
    declare soundx2 varchar(64) default '';

    set spacePos = locate(splitChar, tempStr);

    while searchLen > 0 do
      if spacePos = 0 then
        set tmp = tempStr;
        select soundex(tmp) into soundx2;
        if soundx1 = soundx2 then
          return 1;
        else
          return 0;
        end if;
      end if;

      if spacePos != 0 then
        set tmp = substr(tempStr, 1, spacePos-1);
        set soundx2 = soundex(tmp);
        if soundx1 = soundx2 then
          return 1;
        end if;
        set tempStr = substr(tempStr, spacePos+1);
        set searchLen = length(tempStr);
      end if;

      set spacePos = locate(splitChar, tempStr);

    end while;

    return 0;

  end
$$
delimiter ;
```

http://www.imranulhoque.com/mysql/mysql-function-soundex-match-multi-word-string/

Comment: Works great except it doesn't pickup words that have registered and trademark symbols(™, ®) and my product titles have a lot of those.

Comment: Best thing to do in this case is so strip those characters from the haystack sent to the function.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Now I need to sort it by products that most closely match the searched word. So for example if a person puts "swin" then "schwinn" would be on top of list and "swen" at the bottom. Any ideas?

Comment: Perfect, thanks, how can people write this kind of great code.
Works great

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting this question; I updated @msigman's solution to accommodate strings of different lengths (i.e. 'James' is similar to 'Jamestown')...

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS senf_soundex;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION senf_soundex (_needle VARCHAR(128), _haystack TEXT, _delimiter VARCHAR(1)) 
    RETURNS TINYINT
    DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN

        DECLARE int_index   INT;
        DECLARE int_length  INT             DEFAULT LENGTH(_haystack);
        DECLARE int_result  TINYINT         DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE str_remnant TEXT            DEFAULT _haystack;
        DECLARE snd_needle  VARCHAR(64)     DEFAULT TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM LEFT(SOUNDEX(_needle), 4));
                        
        SET int_index = LOCATE(_delimiter, str_remnant);
    
        WHILE int_length > 0 DO
            IF int_index = 0 THEN
                SET int_result = IF(snd_needle = LEFT(SOUNDEX(str_remnant), LEAST(4, LENGTH(snd_needle))),1,0);
                RETURN int_result;
            ELSE
                IF snd_needle = LEFT(SOUNDEX(SUBSTR(str_remnant, 1, int_index-1)), LEAST(4, LENGTH(snd_needle))) THEN
                    RETURN 1;
                END IF;
                SET str_remnant = SUBSTR(str_remnant, int_index+1);
                SET int_length = LENGTH(str_remnant);
            END IF;
        
            SET int_index = LOCATE(_delimiter, str_remnant);
        
        END WHILE;
    
        RETURN 0;
    
    END
$$ DELIMITER ;
```