# How to search for Soundex() substrings in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, soundex

i got a problem with the Joomla! 3 integrated search engine. This engine's indexer creates so called soundex-values when indexing content like, for example

> Testobject,
>   Testobject 1,
>   Testobject 2239923,
>   Textobject ....

which all have the same soundex-value of T23123.

Now my problem is, if i do a search for `Test`, then there won't be any results since the soundex-value for this term is T230.

The query used by the search engine is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.term_id AS id, t.term AS term
FROM tablename AS t
WHERE t.soundex = SOUNDEX('test')
```

I checked the soundex_match function in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952959/can-soundex-be-used-on-portion-of-a-column-in-mysql/), but unfortunately this cannot resolve my problem, because it does not compare soundex values.

I want to avoid hacking the cms core and would like understand if there is some kind of approximation procedure available to compare soundex-values like for regular queries when using the `%` symbol which i could then try to implement using a plugin or whatever.

The MSSQL `DIFFERENCE` function mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189282%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) would be ideal, if it would be available in MySQL and ready to use a soundex value as second parameter.

I am not very well experienced in MySQL and have no idea how to improve the query to also match soundex-substrings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're probably looking to calculate the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance); but if you simply want to find those records that start with something that sounds similar to the search term, you can strip any trailing `0` (which is merely used for padding) and then search for soundex strings with the resulting prefix:

```
WHERE t.soundex LIKE CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM SOUNDEX('test')), '%')
```

Comment: This is a good idea and i am trying to integrate this check into the soundex_match function. I did some tryings to get a base query working, but why does this query `SELECT CASE WHEN  'T23%' LIKE  'T23123'
THEN  'match'
ELSE  'NO match'
END` return `NO match`?

Comment: @user1014412: The string being matched should be the left-operand of the [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) operator, and the pattern should be the right-operand: `'T23123' LIKE 'T23%'`.

Comment: Aaahhh right! ^^ Too much work for today. This works now. Thanks a buch!

Comment: This answer won't work if t's soundex is short and has it's own trailing 0's.  So the "t" column would have to have already been trimmed of trailing 0's, or if not you would need to call TRIM() on it also like this:   WHERE TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM t.soundex) LIKE CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM SOUNDEX('test')), '%')

Comment: @orrd: No, the `%` wildcard at the end of the pattern already handles that.