# looking for efficient procedure in VB.NET on searching string pattern in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, algorithm, search

im looking for an efficient procedure to query on mysql database using **vb.net** that will look for the string requested by the user even when the string requested is spelled wrong.

As for now, i have this procedure in mind. But i think this will take great memory space on the performance, so I would like for any suggestion or advice.

1. loop through every string index and replace each index character with "%" (mysql wildcard)
2. every loop queries to mysql database to get results
3. results on every loop will be compared if it already exist from the previous loop cycle so you won't get repeated results
4. after the loop ends, results will be ranked according to percentage of string similarity
5. results from string similarity then will be displayed accordingly

for example the user will input "extra" and some in the database records that have a string which contains "extreme","extravagance","extraordinary","trash","programming", the query should return "extravagance","extraordinary","extreme".

Thanks.

Comment: So, you want a query to find all words that contain `n-1` characters like the user input, being `n` the lenght of the input?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995150/how-to-search-for-soundex-substrings-in-mysql

Comment: @JoshPart something like that, im not sure i did understand what you said.

Comment: User inputs "extra", you want the code to query for `%xtra%`, `%e%tra%`, `%ex%ra%`, `%ext%a%` and `%extr%`?

Comment: @JoshPart Yes, that's it.. any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution for your 1st question. But i need more information for the other four.

```
Private Function GetWhereClause() As String
    Dim strSearch As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim strWhere As String = ""

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strSearch) Then
        strWhere = "WHERE"

        For i As Integer = 1 To strSearch.Length
            Dim tmp As String = strSearch
            tmp = tmp.Insert(i, "%")
            tmp = tmp.Remove(i - 1, 1)

            If Not tmp.StartsWith("%") Then tmp = "%" & tmp
            If Not tmp.EndsWith("%") Then tmp = tmp & "%"

            strWhere &= IIf(i > 1, "   OR", "") & " ( FieldToSearch LIKE '" & tmp & "' ) " & vbCrLf
        Next
    End If

    Return strWhere
End Function
```

The result of `TextBox1.Text = "extra"`  would be

```
WHERE ( FieldToSearch LIKE '%xtra%' ) 
   OR ( FieldToSearch LIKE '%e%tra%' ) 
   OR ( FieldToSearch LIKE '%ex%ra%' ) 
   OR ( FieldToSearch LIKE '%ext%a%' ) 
   OR ( FieldToSearch LIKE '%extr%' )
```

**EDIT**

Searching for multiplie words is just another for/next loop.

```
Private Function GetWhereClause() As String
    Dim strSearch() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(",")
    Dim strWhere As String = ""

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strSearch.ToString) Then
        strWhere = "WHERE"

        For j As Integer = LBound(strSearch) To UBound(strSearch)
            Dim strSplit As String = strSearch(j)

            If j >= 1 Then
                strWhere &= vbCrLf & "  OR ( "
            Else
                strWhere &= " ( "
            End If

            For i As Integer = 1 To strSplit.Length
                Dim tmp As String = strSplit
                tmp = tmp.Insert(i, "%")
                tmp = tmp.Remove(i - 1, 1)

                If Not tmp.StartsWith("%") Then tmp = "%" & tmp
                If Not tmp.EndsWith("%") Then tmp = tmp & "%"

                strWhere &= IIf(i > 1, "   OR", "") & " ( FieldToSearch LIKE '" & tmp & "' ) " & vbCrLf
            Next

            strWhere &= " ) "
        Next
    End If

    Return strWhere
End Function
```

My searchstring is `extra,strings` and the result looks like:

```
WHERE (  ( FieldToSearch LIKE '%xtra%' ) 
   OR ( FieldToSearch LIKE '%e%tra%' ) 
   OR ( FieldToSearch LIKE '%ex%ra%' ) 
   OR ( FieldToSearch LIKE '%ext%a%' ) 
   OR ( FieldToSearch LIKE '%extr%' ) 
 ) 
  OR (  ( FieldToSearch LIKE '%trings%' ) 
   OR ( FieldToSearch LIKE '%s%rings%' ) 
   OR ( FieldToSearch LIKE '%st%ings%' ) 
   OR ( FieldToSearch LIKE '%str%ngs%' ) 
   OR ( FieldToSearch LIKE '%stri%gs%' ) 
   OR ( FieldToSearch LIKE '%strin%s%' ) 
   OR ( FieldToSearch LIKE '%string%' ) 
 )
```

Comment: Listed above was just a procedure in my mind on how to get results from the input. Thanks for this. ill try this.

Comment: What if the input is a multiple words? for example: "extra strings". I want to split every words and use it like `WHERE ( FieldToSearch LIKE '%xtra%'  AND FieldToSearch LIKE '%tring%') 
OR (...continue...)` 
(and so on) using your algorithm.

Comment: I've updated the example code to consider your question. Have fun.